# Virtual Enviroment CPU Allocation

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, cpu-usage, hyper-v

I am currently attempting to spec out a virtual environment and I am having a hard time understanding how many cores or "cpu's" I can apply to virtual machines.

Can someone let me know how many usable cores I have in the attached image spec?

In other words, how many cores can I assign to VMs before I hit my limit, or run into issue with performance.

[Server spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I19Rq.png)

(2) xeon silver 4214 2.2 12c per Server

4 servers total. Based on this I should have 192 virtual cores that I can allocate? Or am I wrong??

Answer (score 0):

you have 48 logical processors on 1 server with listed CPU. Now think this way - you might have other VMs that will consume some amount of resources like CPU and RAM. If you will assign lets say 16 cpus to a VM, will other hosts in your cluster (I assume you clustered all 4 hosts) be able to handle the load of other VMs+ this with 16cpus?
You should check VMs usage on idle and with some load so then you could do some calculation of how many cpus each VM should have before you gonna experience major performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for the info, what I am really interested in is the max amount without worrying about roll over. So I would be able to allot 192 cpu's potentially?

Comment: what ever amount it does show in the VM that will be your max available! I guess in your case it will be 24 as max!